# Activiti 6.0.0 UI app / in-memory H2 database in tomcat9 / java version "9.0.1"

Tags: spring, h2, alfresco, activiti, tomcat9

I just downloaded activiti-app from `github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/download/activiti-6.0.0/…` and deployed in tomcat9, but I have this errors when init the app:

```
  11:29:40,090 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.AsyncConfiguration  - Creating Async Task Executor
11:29:40,887 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - Configuring Datasource
11:29:40,910 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - Configuring Datasource with following properties (omitted password for security)
11:29:40,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - datasource driver: org.h2.Driver
11:29:40,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - datasource url : jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
11:29:40,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - datasource user name : sa
11:29:40,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - Min pool size | Max pool size | acquire increment : 10 | 100 | 5
11:29:40,947 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog  - MLog clients using log4j logging.
11:29:41,014 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry  - Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
11:29:41,290 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  org.activiti.app.conf.DatabaseConfiguration  - Configuring EntityManager
11:29:42,220 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge0wdal156qsqtw1cxe|70e1a94b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.h2.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge0wdal156qsqtw1cxe|70e1a94b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 1800, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {password=******, user=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
11:29:43,183 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.activiti.app.conf.SecurityConfiguration  - Could not configure authentication mechanism:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'securityConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dbAuthenticationProvider' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.activiti.app.service.api.UserCache org.activiti.app.security.UserDetailsService.userCache; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userCacheImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.activiti.engine.IdentityService org.activiti.app.service.idm.UserCacheImpl.identityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activitiEngineConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.activiti.app.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.transactionManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'annotationDrivenTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:322)
        at org.activiti.app.conf.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6992200.dbAuthenticationProvider(<generated>)
        at org.activiti.app.conf.SecurityConfiguration.configureGlobal(SecurityConfiguration.java:74)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.activiti.app.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:544)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1690)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1614)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'securityConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dbAuthenticationProvider' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.activiti.app.service.api.UserCache org.activiti.app.security.UserDetailsService.userCache; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userCacheImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.activiti.engine.IdentityService org.activiti.app.service.idm.UserCacheImpl.identityService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activitiEngineConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.activiti.app.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.transactionManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'annotationDrivenTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/app/conf/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 80 more
```

and here my activiti-app.properties file:

```
#
# SECURITY
#
security.rememberme.key=testkey

#
# DATABASE
#

datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

#datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/activiti6ui?characterEncoding=UTF-8

datasource.username=sa
datasource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# 
# EMAIL
# 

#email.enabled=true
#email.host=localhost
#email.port=1025
#email.useCredentials=false
#email.username=
#email.password=

# The base url that will be used to create urls in emails.
#email.base.url=http://localhost:9999/activiti-app

#email.from.default=no-reply@activiti.alfresco.com
#email.from.default.name=Activiti
#email.feedback.default=activiti@alfresco.com
        
#
# ACTIVITI
#

activiti.process-definitions.cache.max=500

#
# DEFAULT ADMINISTRATOR ACCOUNT
#

admin.email=admin
admin.password=test
admin.lastname=Administrator

admin.group=Superusers

# The maximum file upload limit. Set to -1 to set to 'no limit'. Expressed in bytes
file.upload.max.size=104857600

# For development purposes, data folder is created inside the sources ./data folder
contentstorage.fs.rootFolder=data/
contentstorage.fs.createRoot=true
contentstorage.fs.depth=4
contentstorage.fs.blockSize=1024
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `datasource.username` to an empty string?

Comment: What you mean "just downloaded"?? 7 (current), which is not available "as download" (but only as "Cloud" or ""Core"), or 6? (older version, which also contains 3 packed .war's ..cannot reproduce)

Comment: the error message roots from spring-boot:2.6 : [Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default)

Comment: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/download/activiti-6.0.0/activiti-6.0.0.zip

Comment: I fixed it via: `$env:JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS='--add-modules java.xml.bind'` (powershell), but then again: cannot reproduce, works/starts-up "like charm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says you are using Java 9. With Activiti 6 you will have to use JDK 1.8 (Java 8).